# Can't pass {{error}} to handlebars in node.js, but other data is passed

Tags: node.js, forms, express, handlebars.js

I am a noob with node.js & handlebars. Not sure what to do here. I am passing data to handlebars from my code to render "account/register". So "title" works as expected for the tab of the page, but "error" does not. Seems it would all make it or none of it would. I have confirmed with debug that error has a value on the back end, but `{{error}}` at the bottom of the form will not appear. It's just a simple string that I have confirmed is "username is required". I've tried escaping it `\{{error}}` and triple moustache `{{{error}}}`, still nothing. Thought maybe it was a missing dependency but the title is passing. I've also tried passing the data as `error,`, `error: test,`, and even tried `{{#each}}` in the form. No joy.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const { request } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const moment = require('moment');
const db = require('../db');
const authMiddleware = require('../middleware/auth');
const debug = require('debug')('app:routes:account');

// creating instance of router.
const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(express.json());
router.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const password_confirm = req.body.password_confirm;
    debug(`username = ${username}`);
    debug(`email = ${email}`);
    debug(`password = ${password}`);
    debug(`passwordConfirm = ${password_confirm}`);

    // let user = null;
    let error = null;

    if (!username) {
      error = 'username is required';
    }
    
    if (error) {
      res.render('account/register', {
        title: 'Errors!',
        error: error,
        username: username,
      });
      debug(`error = ${error}`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the form:

```
<form id="register" method="POST" class="form needs-validation mt-3" novalidate>
  <div class="my-3 font-weight-bold text-center">Register Account</div>
  <div class="form-group">Please complete the following form to create an account on our website.</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{username}}" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a unique username.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" value="{{email}}" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid address.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password {{error}} </label>
    <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="{{password}}" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please enter your password.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" class="form-control" type="password" value="{{password}}" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please confirm passwords.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="far fa-save"></i>Login</button></div>
  <div class="form-group"><output class="text-danger"> {{error}} </output></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Original poster here, username will not pass either. Just title of the page.

Comment: can you share your project structure?

Comment: Hi nishkaush, I am not sure how I can share the project structure. Do you mean what's in my file explorer?

Comment: Yeh, i feel the issue is with the way handlebars is hooked up to your main route handling file. Can you try creating a different HTML template file and try passing some random props to that, just to check if its the actual hook up problem..

Comment: I tried popping it in my main.handlebars to see if it would show up. No luck. I did try changing the title of the page to the error message, and that worked, but can't get anything in the body.

Comment: I keep getting [object Object] with morgan in the terminal. What does that mean? Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it and got it to work finally, I put my solution below. It's obvious enough looking at it now. Still, I am working off someone else's code that didn't need to do what I did here. Can someone explain why my original code might not have worked?

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const password_confirm = req.body.password_confirm;
    const data = {
      error: null,
    };
    if (!username) {
      data.error = 'username is required';
      res.render('account/register', {title: 'Errors!', data });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

And then this is how I got it to display in the form.

```
<output class="text-danger">{{data.error}}</output>
```